# Doubt with python modules with the same Operators inside

Tags: python, operator

While programming some addons, I created some Operators, which fit all 2 addons.

So I would like to put the operators in a python module which I will call operators.py

Now I would like to use this identical module, in 2 different addons, but I don't know if I run any risks when all 2 addons are activated.

The operators are identical, and they do exactly the same things.

Will there be conflict problems?

Comment: Before the advent of workspaces would have suggested making a single addon (extra objects for example is many merged addons).  For the most part registering another operator with the same `bl_idname` overwrites  prior without "There is already an operator registered" issues. If they're the same won't matter which order they are registered in.  Should you write more addons that use the same operators each time, consider creating an addon with common operators and use `addon_utils` https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/140499/15543 to enable if need be.